# Flutter set background image for a page

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to set the image as the background color for the page but the code below seems not to work well. I'm not sure if there is something missing in my code or mistake inside. And there is no error message shown.

```
class LoginPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _LoginPageState createState() => _LoginPageState();
}

class _LoginPageState extends State<LoginPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.tealAccent,
      body: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          image: DecorationImage(
            image: AssetImage("assets/images/background.png"),
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
          ),
        ),
        child: Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              SizedBox(height: 50),
              _signInButton(),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: do you get an error message? what is the problem?

Comment: There is no error message shown in the terminal.

Comment: also add your puspec.yaml file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to just use `stack` widget just like this

```
Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                image: DecorationImage(
                    image: AssetImage("assets/login.png"), fit: BoxFit.fill)),
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            child: <YOUR CHILD COMPONENTS WILL BE PLACED HERE>
          ),
        ],
      ),
```

Hope it will help!